# Apple Mac Pro scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How does Apple achieve the effect that the Mac Pro is seamlessly moving on this page http://www.apple.com/uk/mac-pro/

I thought that the page was showing a video which pauses and resumes as the user moves down the page, but there are images for each paused state, so I'm not sure that this is happening.

Comment: If you google almost your exact question there is a pretty thorough post here: https://ihatetomatoes.net/apple-mac-pro-page-deconstructed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
$(function() {

    var el = $('.intro'),
        mac = $('#mac'),
        offset = mac.offset(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {

        $('h1').fadeOut(500);

        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            scrollPercent = (offset.top - windowTop) / offset.top,
            scale = 'scale(' + scrollPercent + ')';

        el.css('transform', scale);

        if (windowTop >= 940) {
            el.hide();
        } else {
            el.show();
        }
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/mariusbalaj/pen/qcfox)

[Apple Mac Pro page deconstructed](https://ihatetomatoes.net/apple-mac-pro-page-deconstructed/)